# Black background in iphone with safari

Tags: iphone, html, css, safari

I get a partial black screen if I browse [this page](http://www.lazzarotto.it/) with safari on an iphone, here a screenshot of the error:

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xHiQ.png)

any idea? could it be because an issue of the background image?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your background image it's not loading on the IPhone. I've tested with my IPad and everything is fine.

Try improving your `body` css

```
body {
    font: 14px/16px georgia, times, times new roman, arial;
    background-image: url(http://www.lazzarotto.it/templates/lazzarotto/image/background.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    color: #554e3c; 
}
```

to

```
body {
    font: 14px/16px georgia, times, times new roman, arial;
    background: url(http://www.lazzarotto.it/templates/lazzarotto/image/background.jpg) #fff repeat-x;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    color: #554e3c; 
}
```

Comment: solved, it was a png that for some unknown reason Safary could not read well, I converted it into jpeg and now it's working..

Answer (score 0):

You may also opt for [CSS3 Gradient](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) to achieve the gradient background effect